# Calculating weighted mean and standard deviation

Tags: r, statistics, mean, weighted

I have a time series `x_0 ... x_t`. I would like to compute the exponentially weighted variance of the data. That is:

```
V = SUM{w_i*(x_i - x_bar)^2, i=1 to T} where SUM{w_i} = 1 and x_bar=SUM{w_i*x_i}
```

ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_mean#Weighted_sample_variance

The goal is to basically weight observations that are further back in time less.  This is very simple to implement but I would like to use as much built in funcitonality as possible.  Does anyone know what this corresponds to in R?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that this is an incomplete specification and that what you really want delivered will require better specification of how w_i is constructed and more detail on the limits of summation.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

R provides weighted mean.  In fact, ?weighted.mean shows this example:

```
 ## GPA from Siegel 1994
 wt <- c(5,  5,  4,  1)/15
 x <- c(3.7,3.3,3.5,2.8)
 xm <- weighted.mean(x, wt)
```

One more step:

```
v <- sum(wt * (x - xm)^2)
```

Comment: Hmisc, as it turned out, does just this.

Comment: Note the last line in the answer.  That is the weighted variance.

Comment: Just a hint... If you are thick skulled like me, 15 is the sum of the individual weights.  Weights are then normalized in this case.  I didn't catch that at first.

Comment: you forgot to divide v by n or n-1

Comment: @skan The formula above represents the population variance for the set.  Note that `sum(wt) == 1` so multiplying by `wt` in the expression is that division.

Comment: it doesn't produce exactly the same value than the function wt.var(x, wt) from the library SMDtools, maybe they use some correction?

Comment: It seems this answer currently works best. I think more consistent would be to have 
`v <- weighted.mean( (x-xm)^2, wt )`
Since that also works when weights are not normalized.

Comment: You should also consider whether your weights are frequency or reliability weights. See @Matifou below.

Answer (score 35):

The Hmisc package contains the functions you need.

Thus:

```
x <- c(3.7,3.3,3.5,2.8)

wt <- c(5,  5,  4,  1)/15

xm <- wtd.mean(x, wt)

var <- wtd.var(x, wt)

sd <- sqrt(var)
```

Unfortunately the author of the Hmisc package did not include an explicit `wtd.sd` function. You have to square root wtd.var.

Charles Kangai

Comment: wtd.mean works, but wtd.var in your example gives 'INF'. why is that?

Comment: @Torvon This is now fixed in the development version of Hmisc. https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/issues/69

Comment: sum(wt) need not be 1.

Answer (score 8):

I too get errors from `Hmisc` when using the `wtd.var()` function.  Fortunately, `SDMTools` has comparable functionality, and even calculates SD directly for you, without needing to take sqrt of variance.

```
library(SDMTools)

x <- c(3.7,3.3,3.5,2.8)
wt <- c(5,  5,  4,  1)/15  ## Note: no actual need to normalize weights to sum to 1, this will be done automatically.

wt.mean(x, wt)
wt.sd(x,wt)

wt.var(x, wt)
```

Comment: SDMTools is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Package `Hmisc` has function `wt.var()`, as noted by others.

Note that you need to understand whether you want **frequency** or **reliability** weights. In your case, I believe you are interested in reliability weights, so will need to set explicitely `normwt=TRUE`. In that case you can give your weights in any format (sum to 1, sum to N, etc). If you were to use frequency weights, you would need to be careful about how you specify weights.

```r
library(Hmisc)

n <- 3
x <- seq_len(n)
w <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.6)
w2 <- w / min(w)
w3 <- w / sum(w)

## reliability weights?
wtd.var(x = x, weights = w, normwt=TRUE)
#> [1] 0.95
wtd.var(x = x, weights = w2, normwt=TRUE)
#> [1] 0.95
wtd.var(x = x, weights = w3, normwt=TRUE)
#> [1] 0.95

## frequency weights?
wtd.var(x = x, weights = w)
#> Warning in wtd.var(x = x, weights = w): only one effective observation; variance
#> estimate undefined
#> [1] -4.222222
wtd.var(x = x, weights = w2)
#> [1] 0.5277778
wtd.var(x = x, weights = w3)
#> Warning in wtd.var(x = x, weights = w3): only one effective observation;
#> variance estimate undefined
#> [1] Inf
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The difference between frequency/reliability weights isn't given enough attention. +1

Answer (score 2):

For the *Variance* and *Standard deviation* you have to distinguish between *biased* estimate and *frequency* and *reliability* / *sampling* weights.

```
x <- c(1, 4, 5)
wf <- c(1, 2, 3)        # Frequency counts
ws <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)  # Sampling weights

## Weighted mean
mean(rep(x, wf))        # Works only for integer frequencys
#[1] 4
sum(x * wf) / sum(wf)
#[1] 4
sum(x * ws) / sum(ws)
#[1] 4
weighted.mean(x, wf)
#[1] 4
weighted.mean(x, ws)
#[1] 4

## Frequency counts
var(rep(x, wf))                        # Variance
#[1] 2.4
sd(rep(x, wf))                         # Standard deviation
#[1] 1.549193
sw <- sum(wf)
xm <- sum(x * wf) / sw
sum(wf * (x - xm)^2) / (sw - 1)        # Variance
#[1] 2.4
sqrt(sum(wf * (x - xm)^2) / (sw - 1))  # Standard deviation
#[1] 1.549193

## Sampling weights
xm <- weighted.mean(x, ws)
sum(ws *(x-xm)^2)*(sum(ws)/(sum(ws)^2-sum(ws^2)))  # Variance
#[1] 3.272727
cov.wt(matrix(x, ncol=1), ws)$cov                  # Variance
#[1,] 3.272727

## BIASED weighted sample variance
xm <- weighted.mean(x, ws)
sum(ws * (x - xm)^2) / sum(ws)  # Variance
#[1] 2
xm <- weighted.mean(x, wf)
sum(wf * (x - xm)^2) / sum(wf)  # Variance
#[1] 2

## Using Hmisc
Hmisc::wtd.var(x, wf)
#[1] 2.4
Hmisc::wtd.var(x, ws, normwt=TRUE)
#[1] 3.272727
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmisc package provides this functionality:

http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=Hmisc:wtd.stats