# How to compute weighted mean in R?

Tags: r, mean, weighted-average

How do I compute the weighted mean in `R`?

For example, I have 4 elements of which 1 element is of size (or: length, width, etc.) 10 and 3 elements are of size 2.

```
> z = data.frame(count=c(1,3), size=c(10,2))
> z
  count size
1     1   10
2     3    2
```

The weighted average is `(10 * 1 + 2 * 3) / 4 = 4`.

Comment: Speaking for myself, I downvoted because a google search for "weighted average in R" returns the help page for weighted.mean as the very first result.

Comment: @Frank Hover over the down triangle beneath the vote count next to your Q. The tool tip says: "This question does not show any research effort; ...". Given that someone here has already asked a very similar Q here that could easily be found via a search, and a Google search takes you to the correct Answer, that may be why you got Downvotes and had your Q closed.

Comment: The other question appears to be different, the OP is asking about weighted variance as he clarified in his comment on the accepted answer: _>  yes, i'm looking for weighted variance though. not mean –  Alex Apr 8 '12 at 2:26_

Comment: Voting to reopen; as @ChrisSnow notes, the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049402/calculating-weighted-mean-and-standard-deviation) seems different, and in any case is *much* less clear than this one.

Answer (score 40):

Use `weighted.mean`:

```
> weighted.mean(z$size, z$count)
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 23):

Seems like you already know how to calculate this, just need a nudge in the right direction to implement it. Since R is vectorized, this is pretty simple:

```
with(z, sum(count*size)/sum(count))
```

The `with` bit just saves on typing and is equivalent to `sum(z$count*z$size)/sum(z$count)`

Or use the built in function `weighted.mean()` as you also pointed out. Using your own function can prove faster, though will not do the same amount of error checking that the builtin function does.

```
builtin <- function() with(z, weighted.mean(count, size))
rollyourown <- function() with(z, sum(count*size)/sum(count))

require(rbenchmark)  
  benchmark(builtin(), rollyourown(),
            replications = 1000000,
            columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"),
            order = "relative")
#-----
           test elapsed relative
2 rollyourown()   13.26 1.000000
1     builtin()   22.84 1.722474
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `collapse::fmean` which includes a `w` parameter for weights, and is noticeably fast:

```r
library(collapse)
fmean(z$size, w = z$count)
#[1] 4
```

Benchmark with 10,000 rows:

```r
# Unit: microseconds
#           expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#      builtin() 165.801 239.401 257.67796 246.9515 263.2015 508.201   100
#  rollyourown()  45.501  73.701  81.57205  75.7510  79.7010 196.000   100
#     collapse()  26.301  27.901  32.51103  28.7510  30.7510 122.801   100
```

Code for benchmark:

```r
library(collapse)
z = data.frame(count = rnorm(10000), size = runif(10000))
collapse <- function() fmean(z$size, w = z$count)
builtin <- function() with(z, weighted.mean(count, size))
rollyourown <- function() with(z, sum(count*size)/sum(count))
microbenchmark(builtin(), rollyourown(), collapse())
```