# How can I code the mean and standard deviation for a weighted binomial distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, variance

I'm working on a genetics problem where I have 20 genes which each have two alleles. This results in 40 values that can be 1 or 0.

For this distribution I get an expected value of 20 (**np**) and a variance of 10 (**np(1-p)**) because n=40 and p=0.5 ([see here](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/bin.html)).

But I weight the contribution of each of these genes. The weights are calculated as follows:

```
res <- optimize(function(lambda) (sum(exp(-lambda * (1:20))) -5)^2, 0:1, tol = .Machine$double.eps)
res
x <- c(1:20)
lambda <- res$minimum
y<-exp(-lambda*x)
```

Note that because each of the genes has 2 alleles, each weight is used twice.

```
   gene1.1 * weight1 + gene1.2 * weight 1 + gene2.1 * weight2 + gene2.2 * weight2...
```

I want to calculate the expected value and variance of this new distribution but I'm not sure how to do this in R. Indeed I don't know the mathematical form of this at all.

Hope you can help

Comment: Which package is function `expo` from?

Comment: that was a typo, I've fixed it now. I'm just using the exponential function

Comment: If it's just the calculations for weighted mean & sd, then this may be enough? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049402/calculating-weighted-mean-and-standard-deviation. If its the methodology behind weighting families of distributions, then try moving the question to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given n Bernoulli random variables X<sub>1</sub>, ..., X<sub>20</sub> with the same parameter p and weights w<sub>1</sub>, ..., w<sub>20</sub>, the expectation of their sum is

E[sum<sub>i</sub><sup>n</sup> w<sub>i</sub>X<sub>i</sub>] = p sum<sub>i</sub><sup>n</sup> w<sub>i</sub>

and the variance is

Var[sum<sub>i</sub><sup>n</sup> w<sub>i</sub>X<sub>i</sub>] = sum<sub>i</sub><sup>n</sup> w<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>Var[X<sub>i</sub>] = p(1-p) sum<sub>i</sub><sup>n</sup> w<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>

This gives

```
p <- 0.5
n <- 20

# No weights
2 * n * p # Mean
# [1] 20
2 * n * p * (1 - p) # Variance
# [1] 10

# Weights
2 * sum(y) * p # Mean
# [1] 5
2 * p * (1 - p) * sum(y^2) # Variance
# [1] 1.172048

# Unweighted case again
y <- rep(1, n)
2 * sum(y) * p # Mean
# [1] 20
2 * p * (1 - p) * sum(y^2) # Variance
# [1] 10
```